# forward calls to voicemail in android?

Tags: java, android, voicemail

I was searching and googleing this topic for more than 2 hours but maybe there's something wrong with my search, cuz i didnt find anything.

can somebody help me in this? any topic, tutorial, piece of code?

I want to monitor incoming calls (I think I'll be able to do this part) and send some of them to voice mail. I'm using Android Level 8 platform 2.2

thanks...

Comment: Hey varand, had u get the solution for the above ? i am also want to implement the same functionality , can u help me for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send some codes to activate call forwarding to any number at the network operator level, but might not work with *ALL* operators around the world.

Check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding

```
void sendCommand(String command){
    Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intentCallForward.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", command, "#");
    intentCallForward.setData(uri);                                
    startActivity(intentCallForward);
}
```

Then to forward calls

```
sendCommand("*21*001234567890#")
```

And remove call forwarding

```
sendCommand("##21#")
```

You can play around with different codes that might suit your needs better

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Android contact list, it has column in contact's database with int value.
in order to do what I asked in my question, you need to change that value in DB.

1 = forward to voicemail

0 = do nothing

Comment: That's not necessarily what you asked - I thought you were going to evaluate an incoming call and forward it **at call time** based on some (potentially arbitrary) criteria.  What you're doing is simply programmatically declaring some *contacts* to have all future calls send to voicemail (ahead of receiving those calls).

Comment: Actually I'm evaluating the criteria beforehand, that means once a call is coming, I have already some factors that based on them the incoming call takes the right action. What do you mean by evaluating a call on ringing status(at call time)? bring an example if possible